# InsertBefore() not working properly with variable.insertBefore()

Tags: javascript

I'm new to js and I having trouble with this piece of code, I already try to fix it for more than 5 hours without success can anybody find what I am missing?

This is my code:

```js
function MaterialCreator(materialid, materialNo, thumb , sofaimgboxxx, materialqty){

parentidmaterial = "";
for(i = 1; i < materialqty; i++){

  var newDiv = document.createElement("div"); 
  newDiv.innerHTML = "No. "+ i;
  newDiv.id = thumb;
  newDiv.className = "MaterialSidemenuHorizontal";
  newDiv.style = "background-image: url(/sofaplanner/img/colors/0"+ materialNo +"/0"+ thumb +".png)";
  newDiv.setAttribute("onclick", "javascript:colorFilter(this.id, " + sofaimgboxxx + ")"); 
  thumb = thumb + 1;

 var currentDiv = document.getElementById(materialid); 
 parentidmaterial = document.getElementById(materialid).parentNode.id;

 if(parentidmaterial = "choosematerialInnervs"){choosematerialInnervs.insertBefore(newDiv, currentDiv);}
 else if(parentidmaterial = "choosematerialInnernp"){choosematerialInnernp.insertBefore(newDiv, currentDiv); }
 else if(parentidmaterial = "choosematerialInnerrg"){choosematerialInnerrg.insertBefore(newDiv, currentDiv); }
 else if(parentidmaterial = "choosematerialInnertr"){choosematerialInnertr.insertBefore(newDiv, currentDiv); }
 else if(parentidmaterial = "choosematerialInnerrz"){choosematerialInnerrz.insertBefore(newDiv, currentDiv); }
 
}}
```

```html
<!-- TR - MATERIAL 04 -->
<div id='choosematerialInnertr' class="choosematerialInner">
 <div class="sidemenuTitle">左アーム 生地 TR</div>
 <div id="materialauto4"></div>
   <script>
   document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
   MaterialCreator("materialauto4", 4, 401, "sofa-img-box1img", 23);})
   </script>
</div>

<!-- RZ - MATERIAL 05 -->
<div id='choosematerialInnerrz' class="choosematerialInner">
  <div class="sidemenuTitle">左アーム 生地 RZ</div>
  <div id="materialauto5">
  <script>
   document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
   MaterialCreator("materialauto5", 5, 501, "sofa-img-box1img", 7);})
  </script>
</div>
```

I wanted to use the variable "parentidmaterial"(it contains the result of the parent id) direct with insertBefore, but for some reason it does not work with the variable, only if I actually type the variable result, so I tried with a if, but now it only works for the first Material, all the other materials get Node was not found error

```
parentidmaterial.insertBefore(newDiv, currentDiv)
```

Comment: `parentidmaterial` is a string, not a DOM object, also `if(parentidmaterial = "choosematerialInnervs")` is an assignment not a comparison use `==` or `===`

Comment: "Uncaught ReferenceError: choosematerialInnervs is not defined"

Comment: Running your code produces an error message on the console.  Did you see that error?  Do you know what it means?  `insertBefore` works fine on variables *if* you define those variables first.

Comment: What are `choosematerialInnernp` etc. in your code? They aren't declared anywhere in the question.  Your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Two reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [mcve] **in** the question. Please be sure to read the link so you only include the minimal, but complete, code we need to help you.

Comment: @PatrickEvans Thank you so much, I guess I was getting blind after so much stress on this one. The == was the problem. As for the variable parentidmaterial no beein a DOM object, is there anyway to use the value of the variable as a DOM object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your conditions has a problem,

if you use if statement it should be "==" not "="(assignment)

```
if(parentidmaterial == "choosematerialInnervs"){choosematerialInnervs.insertBefore(newDiv, currentDiv);}
 else if(parentidmaterial == "choosematerialInnernp"){choosematerialInnernp.insertBefore(newDiv, currentDiv); }
 else if(parentidmaterial == "choosematerialInnerrg"){choosematerialInnerrg.insertBefore(newDiv, currentDiv); }
 else if(parentidmaterial == "choosematerialInnertr"){choosematerialInnertr.insertBefore(newDiv, currentDiv); }
 else if(parentidmaterial == "choosematerialInnerrz"){choosematerialInnerrz.insertBefore(newDiv, currentDiv); }
```